# Booting and hard disk errors

Tags: windows, hard-drive, motherboard

Something wrong with my PC (as per linked images below).

I have the following problems: The system shuts down frequently, my pc is very slow and often it freezes requiring a restart. Sometime the hard disk does not show up in the BIOS.  (I changed the HDD but same problem)

I borrowed a 40 GB hard disk from my friend a week ago and set up win 10, but the but same problem is recurring and I don't understand what I need to do to solve it.

The PC Configuration is as follows:

- Intel motherboard
- 500 GB hitachi HDD
- Core i5
- 4 GB Ram

Images can be seen at : 
https://www.facebook.com/saifulsazib/posts/1111108932278824?pnref=story

Comment: Please don't use facebook for images (it's blocked at many workplaces). StackExchange uses Imgur for image storage. Upload your image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're having similar issues with another hard disk, I think it's safe to assume that the problem is something else.

If you changed any BIOS setting, it might be a good idea to reset BIOS settings to their defaults to see if it solves your problem.

Otherwise you'll need to figure out which other hardware component is failing, causing this behavior.  Running [memtest](http://www.memtest86.com/) may be a good idea but whatever error it finds may actually be misleading since I suspect your problem to be with the CPU or motherboard.

Since most weird problems are caused by overheat, it would be a good idea to monitor you're CPU's temperature to see if it is related and if it is, solve it by cleaning up the ventilation and reseating the CPU heat sink with new thermal paste.

If there is no indication of overheat, then you'll need to try a different motherboard or CPU to pinpoint which one is causing the issue.